# Item prototype calculation free/total ( used space)

Tags: zabbix

I'm trying to create an item prototype in Zabbix to get result of Used space, Currently using Vmware Hypervisor template, I tried to create a calculated item with the following formula ""`{vmware.hv.datastore.size[{$VMWARE.URL},{$VMWARE.HV.UUID},{#DATASTORE}]} - {vmware.datastore.size[{$VMWARE.URL},{#DATASTORE},free]}`"" but all i get is the error `"Value of type "string" is not suitable for value type "Numeric (float)". Value "{vmware.hv.datastore.size[https://10.29.4.2/sdk,rjerleljr-eo8D-11D8-9f50-0a94e2END77ab,Datastore name]} - {vmware.datastore.size[https://10.29.4.2/sdk,datastore name,free]}"`
Can anyone please tell me what am i doing wrong? the keys I used are the keys that pull total size and free space info, they already work, they're simple check type.